# Hacer un espacio entre el label y el grafico de barras

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Tengo el siguiente gráfico de barras:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

var ctx = document.getElementById("articulos").getContext('2d');
var ventas = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Ejemplo1', 'Ejemplo2', 'Ejemplo3'],
    datasets: [{
      barPercentage: 0.2,
      label: 'Artículos más vendidos',
      data: [5, 8, 2],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: {
        topLeft: 10,
        topRight: 10
      }
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        formatter: Math.round,
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="box-body mx-auto">
  <canvas id="articulos" width="100" height="30"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
```

Sucede que la segunda barra, el número que está encima de la barra está chocando con el `label`, y mi pregunta es cómo hacer una separación entre el `label` y el gráfico para evitar esto.

*El `label` vendría a ser la parte donde dice "artículos más vendidos".*

Leyendo la [**documentación**](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration), intenté agregando las siguientes opciones al `label`, pero ocurre que el `padding` afecta tanto al `label` como al gráfico:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

var ctx = document.getElementById("articulos").getContext('2d');
var ventas = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Ejemplo1', 'Ejemplo2', 'Ejemplo3'],
    datasets: [{
      barPercentage: 0.2,
      label: 'Artículos más vendidos',
      data: [5, 8, 2],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: {
        topLeft: 10,
        topRight: 10
      }
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        formatter: Math.round,
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        labels: {
          padding: 50
        }
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="box-body mx-auto">
  <canvas id="articulos" width="100" height="30"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes el array con datos:

```
let data = [5, 8, 2];
```

Buscas el máximo y le sumas uno:

```
let max = Math.max(...data) + 1;
```

Y luego seteas la propiiedad `suggestedMax` del eje Y con ese máximo

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
let data = [5, 8, 2];
let max = Math.max(...data) + 1;

var ctx = document.getElementById("articulos").getContext('2d');
var ventas = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Ejemplo1', 'Ejemplo2', 'Ejemplo3'],
    datasets: [{
      barPercentage: 0.2,
      label: 'Artículos más vendidos',
      data: data,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: {
        topLeft: 10,
        topRight: 10
      }
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
          y: {
              suggestedMax: max
          }
      },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        formatter: Math.round,
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="box-body mx-auto">
  <canvas id="articulos" width="100" height="30"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
```

Comment: Capturar el máximo y sumarle 1 en su eje, me parece muy bien pensado, gracias.